# Netsuite Sales Order - set a field value based on another field

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to check my online po field to see if it is empty. If it is, I want it to check the check box when the user saves.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function postSourcing(type){

    var onlineID = nlapiGetFieldText('onlinePO');
    if(onlineID == null) {
    nlapiSetFieldValue('exportCheck', true);
    }
}
```

The error I got was "You have entered an Invalid Field Value true for the following field: exportCheck". The field exportCheck is a custom field check box. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Suitescript - for setting checkbox field use the string 'T' for true and 'F' for false.

nlapiSetFieldValue('exportCheck', 'T');

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having to use nlapiSubmitField to set the values as nlapiSetFieldValue wasn't working for some reason.